# Bulk Import using nodeJS with Azure DocumentDB. Partition Key issue

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm attempting to bulk import a lot of data into DocumentDB using Node. I've created the recommended stored procedure (the one that has been posted numerous times here and on MSDN). However, when I try executing it via Node, I get the following response: "Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted."

The partitionKey on the Collection is "`/id`", and my request in Node looks like this:

`client.executeStoredProcedure('dbs/blah/blah/sprocs/blah', [docs], {partitionKey: '/id'}, ...);`

I can't find any concise documentation on this as it related to Node specifically. Has anyone encountered this issue and is there a solution? I'm completely open to the idea that I'm making a silly mistake, but this is my first rodeo, so to speak, with DocumentDB. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have a data in the set you are trying to import with an `/id` other than the one you specify. If that's the case, I can think of two options:

1. Not use the sproc and load them one at a time from your node.js script. I recommend using one of the async.js functions or the equivalent from some other parallelization library so you can have many requests going in parallel.
2. You can separate the data client side by `/id` and then call the sproc for each set.